# AWS IAM users limit if exceeds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

IAM user limit is 5000 per AWS account. I have more users than this.

Please tell me if there is any way to have more than 5000 IAM users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am quite not sure or convinced that you have a need for more than 5000 AWS IAM Users; the direct implication is that there are 5000+ people or applications who are operating under a single AWS account.

Be sure your application's users aren't the same as your IAM users; example assume you are running a simple Blog / CMS -> which has user roles of admin, content creator, content publisher, content editor; under each roles you have 10 different users so there would be 40 users [ 4 Roles x 10 Users in each Role = 40 users ]. These users would be created under application / infra layers and not IAM users.

The default maximum limit is 5000 users per  AWS account. Beyond which you need to workout a solution with STS - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html.

Again if you need 5000+ IAM users per AWS account; the simplest way is to separate out AWS accounts for individual application [ or also use sub accounts ]

Comment: thanks naveen, can you please tell me about federated user and their policies limit. is there is any limit on federated users and user policy on those users

Comment: If you run an internal development platform where all the services in your organization run, it is very easy to exceed the 500 hard limits. It is a very common use case.

Comment: You can use Cognito (user pool, identity pool) if possible, otherwise, you can offload the user management in a database RDS or DynamoDB with user ID, userName, userProfile.... Hope your found good a solution

Answer (score 0):

in this situation, you can use identities outside of AWS such as SAML, Facebook, Twitter, and Google in your corporate directory. If those users need to work with AWS resources (or work with applications that access those resources), then those users also need AWS security credentials. You can use an IAM role to specify permissions for users whose identity is federated from your organization or a third-party identity provider

you can learn more about that here https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/